# Yoma 45b Ner Tamid - How to light it?

Tags: talmud-gemara, commentaries, talmud-bavli, masechet-yoma, menorah--in-temple

I'm trying to figure out what the text of [Yoma 45b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.45b.4-7?lang=bi) is teaching it's reader.
There is this part (verse 6) about the 'perpetual fire' of the outer court of the mikdash as in Vayikra 6:6. And from this fire coals seem to be derived for lightning the candelabrum (Menorah).

But I got a little bit confused. Is it that the the Menorah had to be lit - on regular daily basis to give light from the eve untill the morning, and then again be lit at eve - by the fire, or coals produced by it, from the mizbeach of the outer court. And in such case, where these coals or this fire transported from the outside to the inner altar in order to light the Menorah there. Or was Menorah taken outside to be lit? The point is I don't quite understand the connection made between these two and in what way one has to do with the other.

Could someone please explain me this concept and maybe show from which verses or ideas Yoma 45b derives it's conclusions/interpretations.

Answer (score 1):

The Ritva explains the fire was brought to the Menora from the Mizbeach, the Menora remained in its place:

> שלא תהא אלא על המזבח החיצון אש מחתה ומנורה מנין. פי׳ אש שחותה ביום הכפורים לצורך הקטורת שלפני לפנים ואש שנוטל להדליק בו נרות של מנורה בכל יום ויום:
>   The fire of the stoked coals (as the Passuk specifically requires coals on the pan Vayikra 16,12:ולקח מלא המחתה גחלי אש) that was used for the *Ketoret* that was brought into the *Kodesh Hakodoshim* on Yom Kippur could only be taken from the Outer *Mizbeach*, and the plain fire (no coals required) that was taken inorder to light the *Menorah* every day could only be taken taken from the outer *Mizbeach*

Since the fire was "taken" the *Menorah* remained in its place and the fire was brought to it from the *Mizbeach* How was this done?
Rashi in Shabbos 22b explains:

> ואדלוקי - לקינסא מנר מערבי ובההיא קינסא מדליק את השאר -
>   He lit the Menorah with a splinter of wood.

Comment: Its in Gemara, I don't understand what you see in the Ritba that is not in Gemara and Rashi